# How to show multiple pin annotation in map?

Tags: iphone

I m showing a pin annotation statically, but i want to do it dynamically to show a lot of pins on map with title and subtitle.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an array of dictionaries with have two objects lat, long and i am doing this -

```
    if ([resultArray count])
        {
            for (int i =0; i < [resultArray count]; i++) 
            {
                NSDictionary *dict  = [resultArray objectAtIndex:i];

                MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
                region.center.latitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
                region.center.longitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"long"] floatValue];
                region.span.longitudeDelta = 70.0f;
                region.span.latitudeDelta = 70.0f;

                MyAnnotations *ann = [[MyAnnotations alloc] init];
                ann.title = @"title";
                ann.coordinate = region.center;
                [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
            }
        }

    //
    //  MyAnnotation.h
    //

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

    @interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        NSString *title;
        NSString *subtitle;

    }
    @property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;


    @end


//
//  MyAnnotation.m
//

#import "MyAnnotation.h"


@implementation MyAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

use this delegate for callout -

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;

    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinView == nil )
           pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
    [defaultPinID release];

    return pinView;
}
```

Comment: This will do in this method ?- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation

Comment: It not shows titles and sub titles. only show pin annotation. Did i need more methods to show this ?

Comment: Titles and subtitles are done, but detailed button is remaining..please help me.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it helps me very much. Again thanks for help and quick response.

Comment: One problem info button not takes click ?

Comment: Hello Saadnib: May you answer my new question.

Comment: actually i can't say anything about it because its working at my end.. use breakpoints to check what is happening?

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947188/how-to-find-out-pin-id-in-map-annotation-view/5947267#5947267

Comment: Info is working but its about to fetch value stored at specific pin with title and subtitle.

Comment: what happen when you click on it, is that your break point in that fuction works or not?