# How to find out pin id in map annotation view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, annotations, mapkit

How can I find out the pin id (i.e. the details of pin title and subtitle) of pin that was clicked?

I have this to show pins annotations. This code is in view did load:

```
[resultCoordinate addObjectsFromArray:[sqlClass return_Coordinate]];

if ([resultCoordinate count])
{
    for (int i =0; i < [resultCoordinate count]; i++) 
    {
        dict  = [resultCoordinate objectAtIndex:i];

        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
        region.center.latitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"Lati"] floatValue];
        region.center.longitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"Longi"] floatValue];
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2f;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2f;

        NSString *fishName = [dict objectForKey:@"Fish"];
        fishName = [fishName stringByAppendingString:@"  "];

        NSString *fishWeight = [dict objectForKey:@"Weight"];
        fishWeight = [fishWeight stringByAppendingString:@" kg"];


        fishName = [fishName stringByAppendingString:fishWeight];

        MapAnnotation *ann = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];

        ann.title = fishName;
        ann.subtitle = [dict objectForKey:@"DateTime"];

        ann.coordinate = region.center;
        [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    }
}
```

and in delegate:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;

    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinView == nil )
    pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
    [defaultPinID release];

    return pinView;
}
```

and on click of info button:

```
-(void)infoButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    recordCatch = [[RecordCatchDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecordCatchDetails" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:recordCatch.view] ;
}
```

Where record catch is new class object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When annotation gets selected map view calls `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` method in its delegate, you can override this to get what you want.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
 MKAnnotation *selectedAnnotation = view.annotation // This will give the annotation.
 if([selectedAnnotation.title isEqualToString:@"yourTitle"])
 {
  // Do something
 }
}
```

If you want to get the action for accessory control click make use of

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
// get annotation details here.
}
```

Comment: Let me more specific. I have 3 pins containing title and subtitle. Let i m choosing first. Then there is info with annotation title. i want to click on info button to show all data related to that pin. and it will call a new class to show data. Tell me how will we detect the pin and its subtitle to show all data in new class, from database.

Comment: you will get the annotation which can provide you with its details, you can then pass it to new view or store in a dictionary and then pass it.

Comment: But title will be dynamic means comes from database. So how can i compare title if there is a lot of pins in map.

Comment: that was just an example. You will get the annotation there. You can store its values for later use

Comment: See my update. Make use of the delegate method i have given in the answer instead of your button method.

Comment: i have but what will i use to find out annotation title and subtitle.

Comment: you will get the annotation details using view.annotation. you can access the details easily using view.annotation.title, view.annotation.subtitle etc